# EEA Family permit- extended family members

Tags: eu, family

I am an Italian full time uni student in the UK and I want my father and sister to visit me here (They are non-eea nationals, but in possession of an indefinite leave to remain in Italy)

They have requested for an EEA Family permit as my family members but it has been refused because they do not qualify as such. Now they are preparing another application, and this time as my extended family members and I have a few questions in regards to that:

1. One of the qualifying criterias of an "extended family member" is proving that they are members of my household, is a Family Status certificate enough to prove that?
2. Would you advice mentioning the regulation that makes them qualify as extended family members, to further validate their application?
3. Are copies of my bank statements and european health insurance card enough proof of self-sufficiency (so, not dependent on public funds)?
4. My tuition fee is funded by the UK government (tuition fee loan), is that a form of dependency on public funds?

Comment: The language suggests it's intended for people who live together. Have you considered going the standard visitor visa route instead?

Comment: Are you referring to the household membership evidence? If yes, then what they are asking for is proof that we have lived together prior to my arrival in the UK. The other route is expensive and it wouldn't allow them to apply for a residence.

Comment: OK, but you wrote “visit” so I did not realise you were aiming for residence. If that's what you want, then yes you have to show you lived together. The visitor visa is of course more expensive and more extensive but there is no way around that, extended family is not covered by EU freedom of movement if they are not dependent/part of the same household (spouses are however). It's the same for example for parents or siblings visiting from a non-EU country.

Comment: I don't think the self-sufficiency criteria applies to you, incidentally, you are covered as a student.

Comment: @Gala Thank you very much for the information, and I apologise for the misunderstanding. The end goal is residence in the UK. So in the case they are both covered by EU freedom of movement as we are part of the same household. I can prove that with our family status and residence certificates.

Comment: @Gala As the self-sufficiency criteria does not apply to me, there is a question on my dad's application about "dependent children" I would like to address. Other than my sister who is under 18 and dependent on him as they currently live together, do I qualify as his dependent child? I ask this question because I am a full time student in the UK and my father supports me financially.

Comment: @Marco yes you are his dependent child, but that doesn't matter since you are the sponsoring principle (the EU national).

Comment: was your application as extended member sucessfulll.

Comment: Oops, that should have been "sponsoring principal."